# Interpolation with Gnu R

Tags: r, function, plot, interpolation

I have not done this in my life, but is it possible to extract any number of points from a given slope/graph with Gnu R? Do be more precise, can I tell Gnu R to give me 400 points alongside the given data (is it not called interpolation even)? Imagine you have the following data:

```
dput(df1)
structure(list(census = structure(c(-281037, -253644, -244513, 
-231730, -228077, -217120, -209815, -207989, -191553, -180596, 
-171465, -129462, -98416, -90381, -80154, -71388, -61892, -33768, 
4582, 11887, 15540), class = "Date"), pop_hist = c(0, 30, 1000, 
2000, 3000, 4100, 3900, 4100, 3900, 4000, 4100, 4000, 4030, 4080, 
2000, 1500, 1050, 111, 1936, 3791, 5167)), .Names = c("census", 
"pop_hist"), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = "data.frame")
```

and the graphical output[image]

**Edit:**
I have this command from the `library(pracma)`:

```
interp1(x=as.numeric(census),y=as.numeric(pop_hist),xi=as.numeric(census),method="nearest")
```

But how can I tell R to give me around 400 points?

Comment: Maybe try [approxfun](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/stats/html/approxfun.html)?

Comment: Linear or polynomial interpolation goes through the points you specify - a smoother (e.g. loess, spline) will try to create a smooth curve which gets "close to" but doesn't necessarily go exactly through the points you specify.

Comment: Thank you both for your fast reply. Please, note the edit I just did in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, thank you *wdkrnls*:

```
library(ggplot2)

test <- approx(x=as.numeric(census),y=as.numeric(pop_hist),n=474,method="linear")
ggplot(test,aes(y=y,x=x)) + geom_line()
```